# copy_blanks(df,column) should copy the value in the original column to the last column for all values where the original column is blank

Tags: pandas

```
def copy_blanks(df, column):

like this, Please suggest me.

Input:

e-mail,number
n@gmail.com,0
p@gmail.com,1
h@gmail.com,0
s@gmail.com,0
l@gmail.com,1
v@gmail.com,0
,0
```

But, here we are having default_value option. In that we can use any value. when we have used this option. that value will adding.like below

```
e-mail,number
n@gmail.com,0
p@gmail.com,1
h@gmail.com,0
s@gmail.com,0
l@gmail.com,1
v@gmail.com,0
NA,0
```

But, my output is we have to default value and skip_blank options. when we will use skip_blank like true, then should not work default value,when we will keep skip_blank is false, then should work default value.

my output:

```
e-mail,number,e-mail_clean
n@gmail.com,0,n@gmail.com
p@gmail.com,1,p@gmail.com
h@gmail.com,0,h@gmail.com
s@gmail.com,0,s@gmail.com
l@gmail.com,1,l@gmail.com
v@gmail.com,0,v@gmail.com
,0,
```

Answer (score 0):

consider your sample `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['n@gmail.com', 0],
    ['p@gmail.com', 1],
    ['h@gmail.com', 0],
    ['s@gmail.com', 0],
    ['l@gmail.com', 1],
    ['v@gmail.com', 0],
    ['', 0]
], columns=['e-mail','number'])

print(df)

        e-mail  number
0  n@gmail.com       0
1  p@gmail.com       1
2  h@gmail.com       0
3  s@gmail.com       0
4  l@gmail.com       1
5  v@gmail.com       0
6                    0
```

---

If I understand you correctly:

```
def copy_blanks(df, column, skip_blanks=False, default_value='NA'):
    df = df.copy()
    s = df[column]
    if not skip_blanks:
        s = s.replace('', default_value)
    df['{}_clean'.format(column)] = s
    return df
```

---

```
copy_blanks(df, 'e-mail', skip_blanks=False)

        e-mail  number e-mail_clean
0  n@gmail.com       0  n@gmail.com
1  p@gmail.com       1  p@gmail.com
2  h@gmail.com       0  h@gmail.com
3  s@gmail.com       0  s@gmail.com
4  l@gmail.com       1  l@gmail.com
5  v@gmail.com       0  v@gmail.com
6                    0           NA
```

---

```
copy_blanks(df, 'e-mail', skip_blanks=True)

        e-mail  number e-mail_clean
0  n@gmail.com       0  n@gmail.com
1  p@gmail.com       1  p@gmail.com
2  h@gmail.com       0  h@gmail.com
3  s@gmail.com       0  s@gmail.com
4  l@gmail.com       1  l@gmail.com
5  v@gmail.com       0  v@gmail.com
6                    0
```

---

```
copy_blanks(df, 'e-mail', skip_blanks=False, default_value='new@gmail.com')

        e-mail  number   e-mail_clean
0  n@gmail.com       0    n@gmail.com
1  p@gmail.com       1    p@gmail.com
2  h@gmail.com       0    h@gmail.com
3  s@gmail.com       0    s@gmail.com
4  l@gmail.com       1    l@gmail.com
5  v@gmail.com       0    v@gmail.com
6                    0  new@gmail.com
```